# How to prevent simplification of hypergeometric functions resulting from integrations?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, special-functions

Definite integrals from `0` to `Infinity` over a product of two hypergeometric (including exponential, trigonometric, hyperbolic, Bessel, etc) functions (optionally times a power of the integration variable) always result in a hygergeometric function (`HypergeometricPFQ` or `MeijerG`). With some experience, many important properties such as the asymptotic behavior at small or large argument can be immediately seen from the hypergeometric notation.

Unfortunately, *Mathematica* takes this nice, compact and very informative output and "simplifies" it into a combination of simpler functions, often resulting in rather lengthy outputs where all the useful information contained in the original hypergeometric notation is lost.

How can I prevent this simplification?
Integrate should result in a `HypergeometricPFQ` or `MeijerG` without further simplification unless explicitly requested via `Simplify` or `FullSimplify`.

Comment: A working example would be helpful.

Comment: ["In many special cases, `HypergeometricPFQ` is automatically converted to other functions."](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HypergeometricPFQ.html) An example would really help to know if it is something `Integrate` does or something the hypergeometric functions do by themselves